# laravel5.1(eloquent) order & extend returned collection

Tags: sql, eloquent, laravel-5.1, where-clause

I've got a transaction table using this design:

```
|id|value|payed_out|...|created_at|updated_at
```

Now I would like to return all transactions ordered by date and limited to 15 which are:

- not payed_out (means payed_out == null)
- not older than 24h (means all transactions which timestamp from now to the timestamp of  "created_at" is <24h)

query could look something like:

```
Transactions::where(payed_out, null)->where(?how to perform the not older check?) ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc') ->take(15)
           ->get();
```

I would need to "extend" the returned collection of the query I described above.

In my view I would like to display the time until the transaction "expire" means I would need to "add" a field into the collection containing the "time" from the "created_at" field of the transaction until now.

Hope you understand my need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try subtracting current timestamp using `Carbon`. See [Carbon Addition and Subtraction](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub). Field `created_at` must be greater than this timestamp to be considered not older than 1 day. For example:

```
Transactions::where('payed_out', null)->
          where('created_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDay())->
          orderBy('created_at', 'desc') ->take(15)->get();
```